# Use XPath to compare values of multiple elements with the same name

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<Fruits>
  <TreeBearing>
      <Name>Apple</Name>
  </TreeBearing>
  <TreeBearing>
      <Name>Orange</Name>
  </TreeBearing>
  <TreeBearing>
      <Name>Grape</Name>
  </TreeBearing>
  <TreeBearing>
      <Name>Apple</Name>
  </TreeBearing>
</Fruits>
```

What should the XPath be to check if each `<Name>` contains the word `ple`?

I tried `/Fruits/TreeBearing/Name/text()` and I keep getting the first item  (ie Apple) only. How do I traverse and get all elements that contain `ple`?

Comment: An example where one or two elements actually contain "pie" would be useful. And so would seeing the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k OP is looking for *ple*  not *pie* for example in *Apple*.

Answer (score 3):

Given exactly this input XML, an expression like

```
/Fruits/TreeBearing/Name[contains(text(),'ple')]
```

will retrieve *all* `Name` elements

- whose first child text node contains `ple` (XPath 1.0)
- whose only text node contains `ple` (XPath 2.0). If there is more than one child text node, this will cause an error, and you'd need to use `contains(.,'ple')` instead.

Yet, in your input XML, there is only *one* such element. Additionally, if there were many of them, your XPath engine might only return the *first* result.

Completely unrelated, but "Fruits" is not a correct English plural form - it should read "Fruit".

---

> also will your xpath return a boolean or Apple?

Assuming the following input:

```
<Fruits>
  <TreeBearing>
      <Name>Apple1</Name>
  </TreeBearing>
  <TreeBearing>
      <Name>Orange</Name>
  </TreeBearing>
  <TreeBearing>
      <Name>Grape</Name>
  </TreeBearing>
  <TreeBearing>
      <Name>Apple2</Name>
  </TreeBearing>
</Fruits>
```

This path expression:

```
/Fruits/TreeBearing/Name[contains(text(),'ple')]
```

returns *element nodes*:

```
<Name>Apple1</Name>
-----------------------
<Name>Apple2</Name>
```

On the other hand,

```
/Fruits/TreeBearing/Name[contains(text(),'ple')]/text()
```

only returns the text content of those nodes:

```
Apple1
-----------------------
Apple2
```

Finally, to return a Boolean that expresses whether such a node exists in your input, use

```
boolean(/Fruits/TreeBearing/Name[contains(text(),'ple')])
```

Comment: also will your xpath return a `boolean` or `Apple`?

Comment: @bouncingHippo It will return  _element nodes_. What exactly would you like it to return? See my edit for some ideas.

Comment: "all Name elements that have a child text node that contains ple" - not strictly true, it will actually return all `Name` elements whose _first_ child text node contains `ple` (XPath 1.0) or cause a type error if any `Name` element has more than one text node child (XPath 2.0).  Not an issue in this case as all the `Name` elements have exactly one text node child, but in general testing `.` rather than `text()` would be safer.

Comment: @IanRoberts You are right, but it's also easy to imagine cases where `.` would go wrong: it would not be safer if `Name` had child elements that in turn contained text nodes. But you are right, my wording is imprecise - I have edited my post to improve it.

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer. Even if it does not compare using only `XPath` functionality (it is impossible to do so from my knowledge), this is the most complete one of all 3, upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether *all* of them contain the value `ple`, you can use:

```
not(/Fruits/TreeBearing/Name[not(contains(., 'ple'))])
```

If you want to check whether *any* of them contain the value `ple`, you can use:

```
/Fruits/TreeBearing/Name[contains(., 'ple')]
```

The last one will also work for *selecting* all elements that contain the value `ple`.